# Google map HTMLMarker (loop different locations)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

What I have is a an array:

```
var data = new Array();                
data[0] = new Array();
data[0][0] = 'First_loc';
data[0][1] = '36.91781,36.63568';
data[1] = new Array();
data[1][0] = 'Second_loc';
data[1][1] = '36.88827,36.636908';
```

After I initialize Google Maps

```
var overlay;

function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.88827, 36.636908);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var name_1 = data[i][0];
        var loc = data[i][1];

        function HTMLMarker() {

            this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(loc);

        }


        HTMLMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
        HTMLMarker.prototype.onRemove = function () {}
        //init your html element here
        HTMLMarker.prototype.onAdd = function () {
            div = document.createElement('DIV');
            div.className = "htmlMarker";
            div.data = "data-price";
            div.innerHTML = '<a href="#' + name_1 + '" class="pin_on_map"></a>';
            var panes = this.getPanes();
            panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
        }

        HTMLMarker.prototype.draw = function () {
            var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
            var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
            var panes = this.getPanes();
            panes.overlayImage.style.left = position.x - 30 + 'px';
            panes.overlayImage.style.top = position.y - 48 + 'px';
        }

        //to use it
        var htmlMarker = new HTMLMarker(loc);

        htmlMarker.setMap(gmap);
    }
}
```

Now I am Looping the functions(and it is not good) And I get the last value so I have two pins on the map with the same values.
If anybody know solution for it? 
So after looping I will have different pins with different values(Location and name)

Comment: Where is loc, being declared in the line.....   this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(loc);

Comment: var loc = data[i][1]; (Just forgot to rename...) But still that wasn't a problem.. a problem is Loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move your marker creation code into a function instead of having it in the body of the `for` loop. Change this code:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var name_1 = data[i][0];
        var loc = data[i][1];
        ...
```

to:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        addMarker( data[i] );
    }

    function addMarker( place ) {
        var name_1 = place[0];
        var loc = place[1];
        ...
```

The problem with the original code is that there's only a single copy of the `name_1` and `loc` variables shared among all your markers, and when the asynchronous code in your `HTMLMarker` markers gets called—long after the loop terminates—these variables have the last values they had in the final loop iteration. By moving that code into a function, you get a closure for each loop iteration so each marker has a separate copy of those variables.

This change also happens to fix a subtle problem in the code: the `HTMLMarker` function was defined *inside* the `for` loop. This is not really allowed in JavaScript, but the various browsers accept it anyway—and different browsers treat it differently. Functions may be nested inside other functions, but not inside loops or `if` statements or similar blocks.

Also, I didn't look closely at the `HTMLMarker` implementation, but it's not ideal to set up that constructor and prototype inside the loop (or now inside the `addMarker()` function). It would be better to move it outside and pass the data into the constructor. And you have a problem with the `LatLng` constructor - you're passing it a string instead of two numbers.

Your marker DIVs didn't have any actual text in them, so I changed it to put the name inside the  tag, and added some CSS styling for them, including in particular `position:absolute`.

A little coding note too: there were semicolons missing on some of the `HTMLMarker` methods. A statement like this should have a semicolon at the end:

```
HTMLMarker.prototype.onRemove = function () {};
```

And finally, the way you were setting the marker's pixel position is wrong. The code was setting the position of the entire overlayLayer pane, not the individual marker. I also changed the latitude of the first marker to give a little room between them.

Fixing all of these, the code looks like:

```
var data = [
    [ 'First_loc', '36.95781,36.63568' ],
    [ 'Second_loc', '36.88827,36.636908' ]
];

function HTMLMarker( place ) {
    var latLngStrings = place[1].split(',');
    var lat = +latLngStrings[0];
    var lng = +latLngStrings[1];
    this.name = place[0];
    this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng );
}

HTMLMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

HTMLMarker.prototype.onRemove = function () {};

HTMLMarker.prototype.onAdd = function () {
    var div = this.div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.className = "htmlMarker";
    div.data = "data-price";
    div.innerHTML = '<a href="#' + this.name + '" class="pin_on_map">' + this.name + '</a>';
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
};

HTMLMarker.prototype.draw = function () {
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
    var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    this.div.style.left = position.x - 30 + 'px';
    this.div.style.top = position.y - 48 + 'px';
};

function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.88827, 36.636908);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        addMarker( data[i] );
    }

    function addMarker( place ) {
        var htmlMarker = new HTMLMarker( place );
        htmlMarker.setMap(gmap);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', initialize );
```

with this CSS:

```
.htmlMarker {
    border: 1px solid #888;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/6qfhF/8/).