# Printing google map with marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to print a particular part of my web page which contains google maps with some markers pointing to some location.

The problem is my javascript function is printing only google maps but not markers. But when I am printing with Ctrl+P, it is printing whole page with google maps and markers.

I am using chrome and firefox browser.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem. Why not my function is printing markers.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
function printDiv(firstDivId, secondDivId, thirdDivId) 
{
    /* Creating iframe for printing */
    ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    ifrm.setAttribute("name", "print_frame");
    ifrm.setAttribute("id", "print_frame_id");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", "#");
    ifrm.setAttribute("frameborder", 0);
    ifrm.style.width = 0 + "px";
    ifrm.style.height = 0 + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);

    /* Creating printableDiv for gethering content divs */
    printableDiv = document.createElement("div");
    printableDiv.setAttribute("id", "printableDivId");
    document.body.appendChild(printableDiv);

    /* Creating printableDiv for chart title css */
    var titleDiv = document.createElement("div");
    titleDiv.setAttribute("id", "titleDiv");
    titleDiv.setAttribute("style",
                    "width:96%;text-align:center;background-color:rgb(255, 238, 182);border-top: 1px solid orange;border-bottom: 1px solid orange;font-size: 16px;font-family: Calibri;border-right: 0px;border-left: 0px;margin-left: 18px;font-weight: bold;");

    document.getElementById("printableDivId").appendChild(titleDiv);
    document.getElementById("titleDiv").innerHTML = $("#" + firstDivId).html();

    $("#" + secondDivId).clone().appendTo("#printableDivId"); **This second div contains the google maps.**

    if (thirdDivId != '') {
        $("#" + thirdDivId).clone().appendTo("#printableDivId");
    }

    // For Landscape style
    var styleStr = '<style type="text/css"  media="print"> @media print{@page {size: landscape}} </style>';

    // With Landscape, It is working in chrome not in firefox.
    var printingContent = styleStr+ document.getElementById("printableDivId").innerHTML;

    // Without Landscape
    // var printingContent=document.getElementById("printableDivId").innerHTML;

    window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = printingContent;
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();

    /* Removing printableDiv and iframe for next time printing */
    $("#printableDivId").remove();
    $("#print_frame_id").remove();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131419/google-map-htmlmarker-loop-different-locations

Read this is something similar.

Comment: The markers are not coming on paper when I am giving this print function. Its working fine on screen.